# USART interrupts in hy-ministm32v board

Tags: microcontroller, c, uart, stm32, stm32f10x

I'm currently doing USART interrupt program and I have kept my code along with this. But the program is not working as an interrupt can anyone suggest me how to fix this?I'm doing a project using the STM32F103VCT6 micro controller and the board used is HY-MiniSTM32V. The soft wares used are STM32CubeMX(for generating c initialization code), Atollic TrueStudioLite (as the integrated development environment), Flash Loader Demonstrator(for flashing the code to the controller) and the Tera Term(for getting the output). Eagerly waiting for all replies.

```
#include "stm32f1xx_hal.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
void Error_Handler(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)

  {
  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      uint8_t data[1];
      //HAL_UART_IRQHandler(&huart1);
          if(HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart1,data,1)==0)
               {
                 HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED1_GPIO_Port,LED1_Pin,1);
                 HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1,data,1,5000);
                 HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED1_GPIO_Port,LED1_Pin,0);
               }

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

/** System Clock Configuration
*/
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/* USART1 init function */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED1_GPIO_Port, LED1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : LED1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LED1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(LED1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1) 
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler */ 
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
   * @brief Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
   * where the assert_param error has occurred.
   * @param file: pointer to the source file name
   * @param line: assert_param error line source number
   * @retval None
   */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
    ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */

}

#endif
```

Comment: You should have a  HAL_UART_IRQHandler defined somewhere, like enabling interrupt USART1. You may no call the HAL_UART_IRQHandler in endless loop, this is a ISR routine, the sytem will callback the ISR once defined.

Answer (score 3):

In MxCube you have to go Configuration -> Connectivity USART1 -> NVIC settings -> Enable global interrupt
Then you will get a defined callback function for ISR. Perhaps you already did thisa and your callback fcn. is HAL_UART_IRQHandler. In this ISR you do something and you clear the interrupt flag , once you leave the ISR.

```
void USART1_IRQHandler (void) {
  volatile unsigned int IIR;
  struct buf_st *p;

    IIR = USART1->SR;
    if (IIR & USART_FLAG_RXNE) {                  // read interrupt
      USART1->SR &= ~USART_FLAG_RXNE;             // clear interrupt

      p = &rbuf;

      if (((p->in - p->out) & ~(RBUF_SIZE-1)) == 0) {
        p->buf [p->in & (RBUF_SIZE-1)] = (USART1->DR & 0x1FF);
        p->in++;
      }
    }

    if (IIR & USART_FLAG_TXE) {
      USART1->SR &= ~USART_FLAG_TXE;              // clear interrupt

      p = &tbuf;

      if (p->in != p->out) {
        USART1->DR = (p->buf [p->out & (TBUF_SIZE-1)] & 0x1FF);
        p->out++;
        tx_restart = 0;
      }
      else {
        tx_restart = 1;
        USART1->CR1 &= ~USART_FLAG_TXE;           // disable TX interrupt if nothing to send

      }
    }
}
```

This code example checks which interrupt has occured rx or tx, and then clears apropiate interrupt flag .